# Make Swift CocoaPod library available for macOS and iOS

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I developed a wrapper for a C library using Swift, where I compile a bunch of C files and construct a Swift class on top of it.

I created this project with cocoapods, and not knowing what platform to choose, I picked 'macOS' to start with.

The problem is that I would like iOS developers and macOS developers to use my pod. It builds fine but when I launched a `xcodebuild` with iphonesimulator of course, It can't find Cocoa ...

```
ld: framework not found Cocoa

use_frameworks!

target 'PorterStemmer2_Example' do
  pod 'PorterStemmer2', :path => '../'

  target 'PorterStemmer2_Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

  end
end
```

What is the best way of making a pod available for all platforms ?
What should I change in the build settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update your podspec to support both targets

**1) If Your files and dependencies are different**

You can create separate [subspecs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec) for lib if those contain different dependencies or files etc (would be like `YourLib/Mac` and `YourLib/iOS`).

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name = 'YourLib'

  s.subspec 'iOS' do |i|
     i.ios.deployment_target = "8.0"
  end

  s.subspec 'Mac' do |m|
     m.osx.deployment_target = "10.10"
  end
end
```

**2) If everything is same**

Just change target to contain both like in [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift/blob/master/ReachabilitySwift.podspec)

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name = 'YourLib'
    s.ios.deployment_target = "8.0"
    s.osx.deployment_target = "10.10"
end
```

P. S. Create demo project on same repo to contain both targets (iOS and Mac) to test things out before pushing to Cocoapods

**[BONUS] Adding another target in demo project**

[image]
[image]

Don't forget to add this target in your Podfile too and `pod install` again

Comment: This is exactly what I tried. But under xcode, the pod is still built for macOS only, and bundles Cocoa.framework. Am I not suposed to modify the Podfile too?

Comment: So it nothing has to do with cocoapod. You just need another target (iOS) in your xcode project

Comment: Should I add it by adding something in the Podfile of my example project ?

Comment: Updated answer to include how to add another target in project. So basically 3 things to do - 1) update podspec to include both targets 2) update your demo project to add another target and update Podfile to include new target

Comment: You have to understand, that your `podspec` is most important part of your library. It basically defines what your library is and what it supports. Demo app is just for you to make sure everything is working fine and for new users to check how it can be implemented in their own projects (a demo)

Comment: Thank you so much. Cocoapods can be confusing. Last question, I see that it should be possible to write `target :ios do` in my Podfile, however it seems that my file wants the full target name. Why is that ?

Comment: You can have multiple targets for same architecture - like iPad and iPhone

Comment: Yes, I know, but my question is why do I have to write the full target name and my Podfile does not let me write `target :ios`. Instead i have to write `target : MyTargetIOSName`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181985/discussion-between-paulius-vindzigelskis-and-scaraux).